# How do I transition the Grid.Row value of a TextBlock, based upon resizing the window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to gain experience at using VisualStateManager, which I haven't much expreience at, in a .NET Core WPF app. I've got a grid on the window, with 3 TextBlocks in it. When I narrow the window to 380 pixels or less, I want to move one of the TextBlocks from Grid.Row 0, to Grid.Row 1. I looked up how I might do this, but the example code I came across made use of VisualState.StateTriggers. However, when I tried to use that in the code I'm working with, Intellisense didn't recognize VisualState.StateTriggers, so I'm not sure how to proceed. And when I resize the window to more than 380 pixels I want to put that TextBlock's GridRow back to 0. I started using a DoubleAnimation, but again I don't know how trigger the change in state. I'm working with .NET Core 3.1, its a WPF app. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">Some text in the upper left</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="UpperRightTextBlock"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Text="Some text in the upper right">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WideView">
                <VisualState x:Name="GoToWideView">
                    <!--<Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="GridRow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Row"
                            To="0"
                            Duration="0" />
                    </Storyboard>-->
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="BottomTextBlock"
        Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        This text is in the bottom row
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why do you need to move textblock between grid rows? You can play with grid layout and rows height or use stackpanels

Comment: @Rod: Move the `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>` element to the parent `Grid` and set the `Storyboard.TargetName` property to `UpperRightTextBlock` or `BottomTextBlock`?.